# SQL update Statement converting to XQuery

Tags: sql, sql-update, xquery

So as the above states I am rather stuck when it comes to converting an update sql query to xquery my example for the update is as shown below.

```
UPDATE Products
SET [List Price] = 19
WHERE [ID]= 1;
```

Where needed just assume a variable, I get how XQuery works and the pathing just use random examples if it's the only way. I just can't find a good example that explains how to update the same way.

```
<Products>
<Supplier_x0020_IDs>
<Value>4</Value>
</Supplier_x0020_IDs>
<ID>1</ID>
<Product_x0020_Code>NWTB-1</Product_x0020_Code>
<Product_x0020_Name>Northwind Traders Chai</Product_x0020_Name>
<Standard_x0020_Cost>13.5</Standard_x0020_Cost>
<List_x0020_Price>18</List_x0020_Price>
<Reorder_x0020_Level>10</Reorder_x0020_Level>
<Target_x0020_Level>40</Target_x0020_Level>
<Quantity_x0020_Per_x0020_Unit>10 boxes x 20 bags</Quantity_x0020_Per_x0020_Unit>
<Discontinued>0</Discontinued>
<Minimum_x0020_Reorder_x0020_Quantity>10</Minimum_x0020_Reorder_x0020_Quantity>
<Category>Beverages</Category>
</Products>
```

This is how the XML looks like, it's stupidly messy hence why I avoided posting it but now it's stuck again

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do update in XQuery, then you need to use [XQuery Update](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-update-10/) and it really depends whether your implementation supports this or not.

As you have not told us what your XML looks like, I will assume something like:

```
<Products>
  <Product>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <ListPrice>20</ListPrice>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <ListPrice>7</ListPrice>
  </Product>
</Products>
```

If so you can use the following XQuery Update expression:

```
replace value of node /Products/Product[ID eq "1"]/ListPrice with "19"
```

Note, that I have assumed that your XQuery processors is schema unaware and does not know the types of your nodes, so I have assumed strings throughout. Also I have removed the space from "List Price" as XML elements cannot contain spaces in their names.

Comment: Thanks for the answer still struggling with it but I can probably work it out from this thanks :)

Comment: @bilbsy perhaps if you told us more, then we could help further.

Comment: I added the format of the XML but not sure what other information I can give (Understand it's messy but it's not my xml doc) also the _x0020_ is just for spacing... also annoying